# как удалить пустой массив с обьекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно удалить массив из объекта если этот массив пустой? Без использования es6

js:

```
$(".js-save-settings").click(function() {
  var event = [];
  $('#eventItems .event-info-view__item').each(function() {
     var self = $(this),
         tabsName = [],
         contactsItem = [],
         customDocs = [];
     ...


     event.push({
           categoryName: self.attr("data-menu-item"),
           tabs: tabsName,
           contacts: contactsItem,
           docs: customDocs
     });
  });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у некоторых элементов нет например `tabs` или `contacts`, но они содержат `tabs: []`, `contacts: []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала формируйте объект а потом передавайте его в параметр

```
var obj = {}
```

На этапе формирования вы можете делать проверки любых данных перед включением их в объект

```
obj.categoryName = self.attr("data-menu-item");
if (tabsName.length) obj.tabs = tabsName;
if (contacts.length) obj.contacts = contacts;
if (docs.length) obj.docs = docs;

event.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте длину массива и удаляйте свойство

```
if (!obj.tabs.length) delete obj.tabs;
if (!obj.contacts.length) delete obj.contacts;
```

Comment: можете на моём примере пожалуйста показать а то я не понимаю как можна это сделать, это es6 вы написали?

Comment: @DimaVleskov на вашем примере придется в параметр функцию пихать, что будет некрасиво. Лучше соберите объект для передачи заранее.